# Reduce complexity in list operations

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

I got a python problem to solve which I did, however I got some critics about the bad performance of the solution....so I wanted to share it here, and check for possible improvements:

The problem was vey simple, it is about finding the minimum absolute difference between the sum of the first part of a list and the sum of the second part.

As an example if we have:

```
L = [3, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

We can split this in four stages:

```
i = 1, abs difference = |3 − 10| = 7 
i = 2, abs difference = |4 − 9| = 5 
i = 3, abs difference = |6 − 7| = 1 
i = 4, abs difference = |10 − 3| = 7
```

In this example the script shall return `1` as the minimum absolute difference.

As I said, that was pretty easy for me and I did:

```
def get_minAbsDiff(L):
    return min([abs(sum(L[0:i+1]) - sum(L[i+1:])) for i in xrange(len(L)-1)])
```

However, seems like this is too time-complex solution O(N*N)

Would it be possible to get O(N) for this problem?

**EDIT:**

It was somebody else who told me about this O(N*N) complexity, I actually do not have any idea about if that is true for this example or not.

Comment: Yes, the code you produced is O(N * N), because `sum()` loops over the elements too. So for each `i` in your `xrange()` loop you loop over all elements in `L` just for the sums.

Comment: @Martin: ok thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to keep summing all elements. Create the sum *once* and update it in a loop:

```
def min_abs_diff(L):
    sum1, sum2 = 0, sum(L)
    min_abs_diff = float('inf')  # sentinel value
    for i in L:
        sum1 += i
        sum2 -= i
        abs_diff = abs(sum1 - sum2)
        if min_abs_diff > abs_diff:
            min_abs_diff = abs_diff
    return min_abs_diff
```

So you start with `0` and `13`, then in the loop this becomes `3` and `10` as you shift the value of `i` over from one sum to the other.

Your solution is O(N*N) because the `sum()` function *also* loops. So for each iteration in your list comprehension, you take N steps as you sum all N elements into two totals, and you have N such iterations.

Comment: Since all answers look pretty good for me I have to take one....I would take this one for the explanation about the O(N*N)!!

Answer (score 5):

The key to achieving an O(N) solution is to recognize that as you move through the list, you are subtracting from one sum and adding to the other. So...

```
def get_minAbsDiff(L):
    leftSum = 0
    rightSum = sum(L)
    minDiff = rightSum

    for i in L:
        leftSum += i
        rightSum -= i
        diff = abs(leftSum-rightSum)

        if diff < minDiff: minDiff = diff

    return minDiff
```

Answer (score 2):

You can incrementally calculate the sums by moving values one at a time from the right sum to the left sum.

Here's how I'd write it, with `sums` generating all partitions of `xs` into left and right, and yielding their sums.

```
def sums(xs):
    left, right = 0, sum(xs)
    for x in xs:
        yield left, right
        left += x
        right -= x
    yield left, right

def min_abs_diff(xs):
    return min(abs(left - right) for left, right in sums(xs))

print min_abs_diff([3, 1, 2, 4, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [3, 1, 2, 4, 3]
sec_part = sum(L)
diff = []
for i in L:
    diff.append(abs(sec_part - i * 2))
    sec_part -= i * 2
print min(diff)
```

first, sum up the whole list, the complexity is O(N)

second, use a for loop to reduce the value, ps: we should reduce double of item, as we add it at first step. the for loop time complexity is also O(N)

third, use `min` to find out the minimum value, the time complexity is also O(N)

Answer (score 0):

I know there are already too many solutions here. Just wanted to add the algorithm most easy on time and space.

```
testList = [1,2,3,4,5]

totalSum = sum(testList)

currentSum = 0
minDiff = totalSum

for a in testList:
    currentSum += a
    minDiff = min( abs(totalSum - currentSum - currentSum), minDiff)

print minDiff
```